# Unable to start Most of the services of HDP2.6.1 Sandbox on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, hadoop2, hortonworks-sandbox, hdp

I have installed HDP2.6.1 sandbox using docker on AWS EC2 [c5.4xlarge - CentOS 7 (x86_64) - with Updates] instance.

I am also able to change the admin password and able to login to Ambari UI as admin user. But when I login to Ambari UI [http:// myEC2 hostIP:8080] I could see all/most of the services are yellow [showing heartbeat lost status].

[image: Ambari HDP Sandbox UI]

I have tried running "Start ALL" but still none of the service is starting, also services which are marked in yellow are not even showing me option of starting that service.

I have not made any changes in docker container setup or to my centos VM. I am not sure what is missing?

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Regards

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using EMR or Cloudbreak? The sandbox itself has not been updated in a few years

Comment: I am new to such administration tasks and not sure about how EMR or Cloudbreak can help me here. Are these options free or chargeable?? Also using EMR would I be able to use Nifi, Apache Tika, pyspark, sparkR, sqoop etc. Hadoop ecosystem tools? Which I get handy with hdp sandbox?

Comment: EMR is just Hadoop. You have to install extra things separately using tools like CloudFormation, Ansible, Terraform, etc, which is what most medium-large companies are using, not a single "all-in-one" sandbox package. Cloudbreak should come with those, since it is managed by Hortonworks (it just installs a distributed HDP / HDF cluster). And both are "free" to use, but you still pay for AWS charges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after doing a lot of debugging, I realized that I was missing an entry in my EC2 instance's /etc/hosts file, Once I made following entry in /etc/hosts file it started working.

I added **MY.EC2.IP.ADDRESS sandbox.hortonworks.com ip-MY.EC2.IP.ADDRESS.us-east-2.compute.internal** line in your /etc/hosts file, Where MY.EC2.IP.ADDRESS is IP private IP address of my EC2 instance.

Then I logged in to my sandbox container using:

```
[centos@ip-EC2.IP.ADDRESS ~]$ ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
enter password: your password
Restart ambari-agent and ambari-server
[root@sandbox ~]service ambari-agent status
[root@sandbox ~]service ambari-agent restart
[root@sandbox ~]service ambari-server status
[root@sandbox ~]service ambari-server restart
```

Finally I went back to Ambari UI and start all required services individually. My sandbox was up and running.

:-)